# How to install and enable ngx_http_limit_req_module nginx module on Ubuntu bionic

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I need to install the `ngx_http_limit_req_module` for nginx on Ubuntu Bionic.

I do find configuration examples everywhere, but I do NOT find how to install or where do I get this as a pre-built module. If I look at the sources on gitlab, I do find it in the `modules/` directory, but if I run `nginx -V` it's not in there. I also use the given repository from nginx-stable (`https://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ bionic nginx`), but I would prefer the nginx package from the default bionic repo.

I'm quite new to the nginx ecosystem, so help would be highly appreciated.

Or is it already compiled in and it's so obvious for everyone (except me), that it's not shown when executed `nginx -V`?

Thanx a lot in advance :)

Comment: Does "nginx -V" show you which version you have?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Sure. It's 1.14.0 from the bionic repo....but I think I found out (from an old debian mailing list), that it' s already compiled within the core. And it's not listed there, but it's used -.-

Comment: And do you have it working now?

Comment: Yes. It works out of the box. I should've just tried it out -.-
But the docs from nginx are very unclear about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it out now and it works out of the box. At least with the plain nginx package (NOT nginx-full or nginx-extras...which should also work) from the Ubuntu Bionic repository. It's nginx version `1.14.0`.

The output of `nginx -V` is

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 
-fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-GkiujU/nginx-1.14.0=. 
-fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
-fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' 
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock 
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid 
--modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi 
--with-debug --with-pcre-jit 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_auth_request_module 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_slice_module 
--with-threads 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic 
--with-stream=dynamic 
--with-stream_ssl_module 
--with-mail=dynamic 
--with-mail_ssl_module
```

So not a sign of the `ngx_http_limit_req_module` and there's also no `.so` file in the module directory, but it's working. So it sees that it's somehow in the core of nginx.

You'll find for example the `ngx_http_geoip_module.c` in the module directory of the sources of nginx (Mirror in Github: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/master/src/http/modules), which you need to specify like seen above. But in the same directory there's also the `ngx_http_limit_req_module.c` module and you don't need to specify that one...so it's totally unclear which module needs to be specified while configuring nginx.

Perhaps this will help someone save time on the research.

Cheers!

Comment: If this worked for you you can accept your own answer to show it is resolved